# Scrape a bit of text using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to program a web scraper that collects exchange rates of currencies compared to the Euro from the website https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html, and I was able to get the actual rates to work, but I also want it to scrape the actual currencies (Such as USD, JPY etc.) and ran into the problem there. I figured out that the actual currencies are stored in the class "currency" but have no idea how to make the scraper to pick that up. My code is as follows:

```
class CurrencySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'currency'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/policy_and_exchange_rates/euro_reference_exchange_rates/html/index.en.html'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        test = response.css('div.forextable')
        currency = test.css('div.forextable::text').extract()
        rate = response.css('.rate::text').extract()
        yield {'currencytext': currency}
        yield {'rate': rate}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see that all currencies are under the same `<td id="ACRONYM" class="currency">`. Using xpath can help you with that.

```
 currency = response.xpath('//td[@class="currency"]//text()').extract()
```

Answer (score 1):

To extract the abbreviations of currencies (i.e. USD, JPY, ...) with css-selectors use:
`currency_short = response.css('.currency a::text').extract()`

Same result but with xpath-selectors:
`currency_short = response.xpath('//td[@class="currency"]//text()').extract()`

To extract the full title of the currencies (i.e. US dollar, Japanese ye, ...) with css-selectors use:
`currency_long = response.css('.forextable .alignLeft a::text').extract()`

Same result but with xpath-selectors:
`currency_long = response.xpath('//td[@class="alignLeft"]//text()').extract()`

[SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) is a nice, interactive tool for finding the selector you are looking for. You can use it either via the Chrome extension or use the bookmark-method described on their website.

As an alternative you could use the build-in tools from your browser as well. In Firefox for example simply right-click on an element of interest and choose Inspect Element. This will open the Inspector and point you right at the element of interest with it's classes, ids and so on.